# Conditional join to determine joining table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables `emp, d1, d2`. Tables d1 and d2 have almost same structure.
I need to join emp table with either `d1` or `d2` depending on the value of column `deptno` in `emp` table. My query which I have written is not working and giving syntax error:

> Error Code: 1064
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
>       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE

```
SELECT
  e.`empno`,
  e.`ename`,
  e.`job`,
  e.`mgr`,
  e.`hiredate`,
  e.`sal`,
  e.`comm`,
  e.`deptno`
FROM
  `emp` e
  JOIN
  CASE
    WHEN e.deptno <= 20
    THEN
     d1 ON e.deptno = d1.`deptno`
    ELSE
     d2 ON e.deptno = d2.`deptno`
    END;
```

Comment: Left Join both tables and see which one is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "conditional" join.  You can do:

```
SELECT e.*,
       COALESCE(d1.col1, d2.col1) as col1
FROM emp e LEFT JOIN
     d1
     ON e.deptno = d1.deptno AND e.deptno <= 20 LEFT JOIN
     d2
     ON e.deptno = d2.deptno AND e.deptno > 20;
```

Note that your query does not not select anything from the `d1` or `d2`.  In that sense, the `JOIN` is not needed at all.  Note the logic in the `SELECT` for getting values from columns.

If you are using the joins for filtering, then add:

```
WHERE d2.deptno IS NOT NULL OR d1.deptno IS NOT NULL.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what a UNION SELECT is for:

```
SELECT e.`empno`, e.`deptno` 
FROM `emp` e JOIN d1 ON e.deptno = d1.`deptno`
WHERE e.deptno <= 20
UNION
SELECT e.`empno`, e.`deptno` 
FROM `emp` e JOIN d2 ON e.deptno = d2.`deptno` 
WHERE e.deptno > 20
```

Just make sure that both selects pick same amount and type of columns.